# remove @username1 in a text file

Tags: str-replace

I have a text file look like this:

```
@username1 bla bla bla bla bla

@username2 hello hi
```

I want to remove `@username1` and `@username2` so my text file has only

```
bla bla bla bla

hello hi
```

I used `.replaceAll("@\\p{L}+", "")` but it only removes `@username` and keeps the numbers.

Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Did you try to add `\d*` This will match any digit character 0 or more times? I don't know if it is required that usernames have a number or not, if so then change the `*` to a `+`  Also what language are you doing this in?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex expression to this. This should work. I didn't test it.

```
 @\w+\d*\s
```